# Как правильно сделать меню?

Tags: меню, вёрстка, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать менюшку? Проблема в нижней стрелочке, которая появляется при наведении:

[image]

Comment: Объясните, в чем проблема? Если просто не знаете, как реализовать, то вот: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ 

Можно сделать с помощью псевдоэлемента `:after`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [так](http://cssarrowplease.com/). А появление псевдоэлемента вешайте уже на `:hover`

Например, так:

```
.class:hover:before {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Делаете для `li :after`, делаете иконку `after` таким же цветом как весь блок. Ставите для `:after` высоту, ширину и `margin: 0 auto;` Делайте `li:hover:after{display: block;}`
2. Через `border` так же добавляем `after` для `li` или `a` и вместо высоты, ширины, `background` ставите:

```
{
border-top: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
border-left: 5px solid #ccc;
}
```